# ASP.NET Custom Validator Client side & Server Side validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net, validation

In my web page I'm trying to preform validation on the client side and the server side. if the drop down and the text box are empty I need to show an error message but if one of them is filled out the validation should pass.
Is there way to create one CustomValidator for both controls?? I have a feeling I'm not doing it right.

Client Side code:

```html
 <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStates" runat="server"  Width="128px">
                             <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Nevada</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Uta</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Oregon</asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                 <td>
                     <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvddlState" runat="server"
                     ClientValidationFunction="StatesCheck"
                     OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
                     ErrorMessage="(*) State is required" ForeColor="Red"
                     Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStates" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvtxtStates" runat="server"
                     ValidateEmptyText="true"
                     ClientValidationFunction="StatesCheck"
                     OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
                     ControlToValidate="txtStates"
                     ErrorMessage="(*) Text cannot be empty" ForeColor="Red"
                     Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                      <asp:Button  ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

     <div id="divErrorMessage" runat="server" class="alert alert-danger" visible="false"></div>
 

<script type="text/javascript">

    'Use Strict';
    function StatesCheck(source, args) {
        var ddlStates = document.getElementById("<%=ddlStates.ClientID%>");
        var txt = document.getElementById('<%=txtStates.ClientID%>').value;
        var state = ddlStates.options[ddlStates.selectedIndex].value;

        if (ddlStates !== null) {
            if ((state === "") && (txt === "")) {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Server Side Code:

```html
Public Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        Try
            divErrorMessage.Visible = False
            divErrorMessage.InnerText = ""


            Dim ddlSelection As String = ddlStates.SelectedItem.Text
            Dim statesText As String = txtStates.Text.Trim()
            If statesText = String.Empty And ddlSelection = String.Empty Then
            Else
                divErrorMessage.Visible = True
                divErrorMessage.InnerText = "(*) Text cannot be empty"
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ServerValidation(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
        If (ddlStates.SelectedItem.Text = String.Empty) And (txtStates.Text.Length = 0) Then
            args.IsValid = False
        Else
            args.IsValid = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an answer from both codes on Server Side and Client Side? I want to answer the Server Side

```
Protected Sub ServerValidation(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
        If (ddlStates.SelectedItem.Text = String.Empty) And (txtStates.Text.Length = 0) Then
            args.IsValid = False
        Else
            args.IsValid = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

Based on my expirience, Im not quite good in ASP.net but based on ypur code above, theres nothing wrong however the part you are saying `but if one of them is filled out the validation should pass` doesnt show here can you please try to do this one.

```
 Protected Sub ServerValidation(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
            If (ddlStates.SelectedItem.Text = String.Empty) Or (txtStates.Text.Length = 0) Then
                args.IsValid = False
Else
                args.IsValid = True
            End If

        End Sub
```

or maybe

```
Protected Sub ServerValidation(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
        If (ddlStates.SelectedItem.Text = String.Empty) And (txtStates.Text.Length = 0) Then
            args.IsValid = False
        ElseIf (ddlStates.SelectedItem.Text <> String.Empty) then
          args.IsValid = True
        ElseIf (txtStates.Text <> "") then
          args.IsValid = True
        Else

            args.IsValid = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet where you can evaluate both controls with a `CustomValidator`

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="input failed" ClientValidationFunction="myFunction"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(sender, element) {
        if (document.getElementById("<%= ddlStates.ClientID %>").selectedIndex == 0 && document.getElementById("<%= txtStates.ClientID %>").value != "") {
            element.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            element.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side validation for the above scenario.

```
  <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStates" runat="server" Width="128px">
                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Nevada</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Uta</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oregon</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStates" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="lbltxtstate" style="display: none;">Please select a state or enter a state.</label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return validateState();" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateState(){
            if (($('#<%=ddlStates.ClientID %> option:selected').text() == "") && ($('#<%=txtStates.ClientID %>').val() == "")) {

            $('#lbltxtstate').attr('style', 'display:block');
            $('#lbltxtstate').attr('style', 'color:red');
            return false;
        }
        else {           
               $('#lbltxtstate').attr('style', 'display:none');
               return true;
        };

    }
    </script>
```